# Read from Excel Worksheet Truncating - Power Automate Desktop

Tags: excel, power-automate, office-scripts, power-automate-desktop

It seems there is a bug or an intentional limit to the amount of bytes that can be transferred through the Action in Power Automate desktop Read from Excel Worksheet.

I have a lot 200 words that I try and extract from a single cell. When doing so, only part of the data is extracted (about 2/3rds), the rest being truncated.

Any idea how to fix or is this an intentionally limiter?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be the case, here I have written "ABC" 500 times, copied it from A1, pasted into A4, and it is the same length.

Have also tried viewing the variable while the process is paused, copying and pasting it, same result, I still see all 500 words.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response and testing. Interesting that it would work for you. I retested and get the same issue as before using my data of 16,000 characters. The data is JSON formatted so wonder if that's the issue.

Comment: If you suspect a specific format is the cause, you would have to share the specific format you're using. All we can say from your original post is that there is no 200-word limit. I would say it is extremely unlikely there is some low limit to JSON - I'm sure MS knows and accounted for typical JSON use in power automate. Most likely the issue is with your specific data, workflow, destination excel file, etc. Are you exceeding the Excel limit of 32,767 characters per cell?